# Why does the surface area integral need the arc length differential but the volume doesn't?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, surfaces, volume

When calculating the surface area of a revolution you need to use the arc length differential $$\sqrt{1 + y'^2}$$ but you don't need to use that when calculating the volume. Why is that? Thanks!